# Using Django Models across Apps

Tags: django, django-models

Good afternoon,

I have seen similar questions but none of the answers really resonate with me.  I am new to django development and am trying to get use to the models.  My question is how do I utilize a model from one app in another appropriately?

For instance, I have a project, Project 1 that consists of the a Person app that manages the users profile.  This app has the model for a person, but then that person is used in Activities for the activities they have completed, and another progress in a game.  All of these apps need the person to be the key.

I am not understanding how to make these relate.

Thanks for your help as I become django-ified.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just by importing model to other apps:

```
from person.models import Person
```

and then you can any relevant thing with model Person, for example:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Make sure that you imported model `Person` in the file before using it.
You can also do something like this:

```
from person.models import Person

def list(request):
    person_list = Person.objects.all()
```

I hope you got idea of how to use one app model in another app in `django`.

Either you want to use app_1 model to app_2 `models.py` or `views.py` or somewhere else, just import that model and use it as per your requirement in your application.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Especially for the ForeignKey, that really clears it up.

Comment: @Sahan Can you please provide more details on it? ideally, it should not create any issues in the IDEs.