# DJango Models & Apps

Tags: django, django-models

Good afternoon,

I am new to Django and having trouble conceptualizing how to lay out some of my apps in a project.  I get the obvious apps for "ActivityTracking" & "GameStats"

Where I am struggling is the glue that ties all of this together - the Person.  I was helped yesterday on importing the Person model into apps to use a Foreign Key of the models ([Using DJango Models across Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825885/using-django-models-across-apps/45826088#45826088)) but I am struggling at where to put my PersonModel (what app?)

There are three scenarios in my app.  The AppAdmin who will create / delete / import / move between departments of users (among other items of overall administration such as onboarding data sources).  A particular user will be able to manage his own Person object to update information and see his/her own statistics, and a team leader will be able to see his departments performance.

Where would this Person model go to appropriately be positioned for these three use cases?

Sorry if I am not asking this well, but I am having a hard to conceptualizing where to place this central piece of the overall application.

Thank you for your insight.

EDIT: Basically the crux of my question is: Is it considered OK in "The Way of Django" to have an app that has no views, URLs, or templates, its sole purpose to have a model that is utilized by the other apps?

Thank you!

Comment: So the more I am digging in, it seems like the best bet would be to use the Django User model, create a separate model for the extra desired fields and tie them together with a one-to-one.  However, conceptually with my original question, does it make sense to have an app that JUST holds the model and doesn't have any views?  The views are part of the other apps and tie into that model?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with this description from Django documentation:

> The term application describes a Python package that provides some set of features. Applications may be reused in various projects.
>
> Applications include some combination of models, views, templates, template tags, static files, URLs, middleware, etc. They’re generally wired into projects with the INSTALLED_APPS setting and optionally with other mechanisms such as URLconfs, the MIDDLEWARE setting, or template inheritance.

As you can see, Django's app is defined here as a *package that provides some set of features*.

The implication here is that those features are semantically, conceptually and physically separated (physically meaning operating on different classes) so that they can be naturally decoupled. This is the goal you should be aiming for when designing your architecture.

Example: In a generic e-shopping portal you will have some kind of `Account` and `Product`. Then it is natural to divide views into apps `accounts` and `shop` (for example), where `accounts` is reponsible for managing user-related information and `shop` for manipulating product-related information. Both apps have separate urls, models, views, etc.

However, clean separation may not be always possible. In your case, as I understand it, the core object is `Person`. Moreover, all three use-cases operate on `Person`. Based on this information one might assume that those views are related and should be placed in a single app. Of course, there are no go-to solutions here and you have to trade-off between a lot of things. For example, how many views are you going to write? 10 views are fine for one file (`views.py`) but in case of 100 I would consider splitting them into multiple files (if not apps). On the other hand, it's way more convienent to keep models close to views that import them.

One common practice is to maintain app named `common` for all handy things. However, I never had to hold my mission-critical models in it and I would not recommend it.

> Is it considered OK in "The Way of Django" to have an app that has no views, URLs, or templates, its sole purpose to have a model that is utilized by the other apps?

It's fine if there is really good reason for it, but I would be very suspicious of bad architecture. That's a red flag for me.

All in all I would classify your three use-cases in the following way:

> The AppAdmin who will create / delete / import / move between departments of users (among other items of overall administration such as onboarding data sources).

That's `management` or `accounts`. This app defines `Person` model - it's semantically consistent.

> A particular user will be able to manage his own Person object to update information

That's in `management`/`accounts` too.

> [...] and see his/her own statistics, and a team leader will be able to see his departments performance.

Those two belong in something like `statistics`. This app imports `Person` from `management`.